# how to notify RecyclerView which is added as a child to LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-adapter, notify

I was about to implement a recyclerView within recyclerView and finally I figured out that I can implement it as LinearLayout which host my RecyclerViews.

```
RecyclerView rv = new RecyclerView(this);
rv.setLayoutParams(new GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
rv.setAdapter(new Adapter(...));

hostLinearLayout.addView(rvSingleMonth);
```

Now I want to notify all those RecyclerView as a child of LinearLayout, simultaniously.

```
if (llRootView != null) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < hostLinearLayout.getChildCount(); idx++) {
        try {
            RecyclerView currentRv = (RecyclerView) hostLinearLayout.getChildAt(idx);
            currentRv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

But it does't work!!! can anyOne help me out?

**Edit**

by "it does't work", I mean when I try to notify recyclerView (as a child of hostLinearLayout) as it shown above,

```
RecyclerView currentRv = (RecyclerView) hostLinearLayout.getChildAt(idx);
currentRv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

notifying doesn't apply changes And it make application lag.

Comment: "it does't work!!!" is not enough to allow us to help you. Please explain what is happening that you don't want and what is not happening that you do want.

Comment: @jwpfox: I've edited my question.